# objective-c class variables: when is dealloc called?

Tags: objective-c, class, variables, static

If I declare class variables in Objective-C, when is the memory released?

If my interface is:

```
@interface TestClass : NSObject
{
}

+ (NSString)instanceCount;

@end
```

And in the implementation, I declare:

```
static NSString instanceCount;
```

How do I release this class level variable? i.e. when is the dealloc called for class variables in Objective-C?

Comment: Just came across this question while learning Obj-C. Apple seem to suggest that there's no such thing as a "class variable" and what you've defined in the interface is rather a class *method*, that's separate from the static variable and thus needs to be defined in the implementation. The static variable is limited to the scope of the implementation *file*, not the class itself. Maybe this is a minor quibble but it confused me for a sec:

http://developer.apple.com/mac/library/DOCUMENTATION/Cocoa/Conceptual/ObjectiveC/Articles/ocObjectsClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP30001163-CH11-TPXREF118

Answer (score 10):

The short answer to your question is: "when the program exits."

Static variables are allocated at the very beginning of your program, before the `main()` function begins. Similarly, they will be released at the very end of your program, shortly after `main()` exits. This memory management is handled by the Objective-C runtime, and it all happens behind the scenes.

If you are trying to monitor this behavior, you probably won't have much luck. For example, if you did the following in a custom class, and then used that class as a static member of another class:

```
- (void)dealloc
{
    NSLog(@"I am being deallocated");
    [super dealloc];
}
```

You would never see this message appear in the log. There are a couple of reasons for this. One, the variables that `NSLog()` requires may already have been deallocated as part of the normal shutdown procedure. And two, because the runtime system may simply release all of the remaining memory in a single shot, without bothering to call the `dealloc` methods.

This can be problematic if your custom class does something important in its `dealloc` method. If this is the case, consider writing a custom `cleanup` method which you call for these objects just before the program exits.

Comment: not to mention the fact that dealloc is an instance method and could get called 0 or 100 times for the class

Comment: Hmm, yes, but I was thinking of this method in an object that was used as a static member of another class. I've (hopefully) cleared that up in my answer. Thank you for pointing it out!