# What needs to be released in the AppDelegate?

Tags: ios, delegates, memory-leaks, viewcontroller

I have a project that I created by using Xcode's Single View Application template. Obviously, it comes with a view controller and an app delegate file. Everything works fine. I just wanted to use Xcode's Analyze tool for the first time to make sure everything is fine before submitting to the App store. I get the potential leak error for the following lines of code in the app delegate:

```
self.viewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController"     bundle:nil]; 
self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
```

Full app delegate is as follows:

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:    (NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
    self.window = [[UIWindow alloc] initWithFrame:[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds]];
    // Override point for customization after application launch.
    self.viewController = [[myViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"myViewController" bundle:nil]; 
    self.window.rootViewController = self.viewController;
    [self.window makeKeyAndVisible];
    return YES;
}
```

I didn't modify the app delegate myself. I am using whatever the template gave me. Do I need to release something somewhere in the app delegate? If so, what? and in which method of app delegate?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nothing needs to be released in the application delegate since the app is terminating and the OS will recover all resources.  Indeed, it is improbably that dealloc will even be called.

See [SO link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5079563/does-dealloc-method-being-executed-normally-when-quitting-the-application/5081201#5081201) for more information.

If you need to do cleanup when the app quits, use `applicationWillTerminate:`.

Comment: Thanks a lot CocoaFu! I guess I should just ignore what Analyze tool complains about, in this case at least.

Answer (score 0):

The line
     `self.viewController = [[myViewController alloc] ...`
allocates an instance and then assigns it to the property `self.viewController`. On the alloc, the reference count will be 1, but assigning to a property with `retain` set will increment the reference count again.

Since the reference count is only decremented by 1 in the dealloc, this object will never be freed = a leak.

See the section on Objective-C memory management in the iOS developer docs for more details.

Comment: I know basics of memory management. Just didn't know if there is a need to do something in this case. I am going to trust the other answer that says I don't need to do anything here. Thanks a lot.