# Analyzing memory leaks on iPad project

Tags: ios, objective-c, memory-leaks, nsmutablearray

I've created a ipad application and now I'm doing some test with Instruments to found memory leaks and other problem.

I've found some leaks, but I can't understand why they are considered memory leaks... Someone can help me to understand?

```
NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
```

Why is this a memory leak? Doesn't it create an array autoreleased?

Comment: the leak isn't obviously related to this line of code. What didn't you tell us ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I still write my answer.

There is no memory leak in this line. You create `secondArray` and it points to the same objects from `firstArray`. arrayWithArray returns autoreleased object, so you haven't to release it.

But I guess that analyzer says than here is a potential situation when you have multiples pointers to one object. And when you release firstArray, then secondArray will refer to undefined memory. It can lead to SIGABRT.

Answer (score 3):

`arrayWithObjects` results in an autoreleased array, but with `arrayWithArray` you are retaining `firstArray` in `secondArray`, without releasing `firstArray` afterwards.

Comment: I checked my code, but firstArray is ay is defined as property and is retained, and in dealloc in release, so I thought it was right.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/661233/objective-c-class-variables-when-is-dealloc-called  So until dealloc is called, you can have tons of leaks. That's why the memory management issue is so important. Because the application can crash long time before dealloc is called. I usually don't even think at dealloc, and try to look at the view controller's life as it isn't there. I release all my objects in dealloc just as standardization.

Answer (score 2):

It does! But how about firstArray? you are retaining it in the secondArray without copying it. So you should probably release the `firstArray` like this

```
NSArray *firstArray = [NSArray alloc] init];

...

NSMutableArray *secondArray = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:firstArray];
[firstArray release];
```

Comment: Maybe I missing something, but why secondArray _retains_ first one?

Comment: Thanks for reply: firstArray is defined as property and is retained, and in dealloc in release, so I thought it was right.

Comment: @MarcoPace, firstArray is iVar. If it was a property, then you used it as self.firstArray.

Comment: @beryllium, firstArray becomes retained in secondArray with the arrayWithArray option. This means that secondArray holds a referens to firstArray aswell; thus increasing the retain-counter with +1. You then have to release the firstArray in order to decrease the retain-counter so that when secondArray is released the counter on firstArray becomes zero and therefor is released. Sorry for not being clear here but i hope you get the picture =)

Comment: @helk, No. You are not correct. `arrayWithArray` returns autoreleased object, it doesn't increase retainCount.

Comment: Maybe just the objects in firstArray is retained and not the whole array.